# Leaflet Heatmap won't display if I change from urls in the head tag to import statements in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, leaflet, heatmap

I am attempting to add a heatmap to an existing leaflet project in Angular 4.2.5/5.2.5 dot net app using leaflet.js (1.3.1), heatmap.js (2.0.5) and leaflet-heatmap.js (1.0.0). I have successfully got leaflet-heatmap working in an Angular 2/3/4/5 project by putting relevant urls in the HEAD tag of my site, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Heatmap</title>
    <base href="~/" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/leaflet.css" />

    <script src="~/scripts/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/heatmap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/leaflet-heatmap.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/vendor.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
```

In my heatmap.component page I have:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

import * as L from "leaflet";
//import "heatmap.js/build/heatmap.min.js";
//import "types.leaflet.heatmap";
//import "leaflet-heatmap/leaflet-heatmap.js";
//import "leaflet-heatmap";

declare var HeatmapOverlay: any;

@Component({
    selector: "heatmap-component",
    template: `<div class="heatmap" id="map-canvas" style="height:500px;width:500px"></div>`
})
export class HeatmapComponent {

    ngOnInit() {

        var testData = { max: 8, data: [{ lat: 24.6408, lng: 46.7728, count: 3 }, { lat: 50.75, lng: -1.55, count: 1 }, { lat: 52.6333, lng: 1.75, count: 1 }, { lat: 48.15, lng: 9.4667, count: 1 }, { lat: 52.35, lng: 4.9167, count: 2 }, { lat: 60.8, lng: 11.1, count: 1 }, { lat: 43.561, lng: -116.214, count: 1 }, { lat: 47.5036, lng: -94.685, count: 1 }, { lat: 42.1818, lng: -71.1962, count: 1 }, { lat: 42.0477, lng: -74.1227, count: 1 }, { lat: 40.0326, lng: -75.719, count: 1 }, { lat: 40.7128, lng: -73.2962, count: 2 }, { lat: 27.9003, lng: -82.3024, count: 1 }, { lat: 38.2085, lng: -85.6918, count: 1 }, { lat: 46.8159, lng: -100.706, count: 1 }, { lat: 30.5449, lng: -90.8083, count: 1 }, { lat: 44.735, lng: -89.61, count: 1 }, { lat: 41.4201, lng: -75.6485, count: 2 }, { lat: 39.4209, lng: -74.4977, count: 1 }, { lat: 39.7437, lng: -104.979, count: 1 }, { lat: 39.5593, lng: -105.006, count: 1 }, { lat: 45.2673, lng: -93.0196, count: 1 }, { lat: 41.1215, lng: -89.4635, count: 1 }, { lat: 43.4314, lng: -83.9784, count: 1 }, { lat: 43.7279, lng: -86.284, count: 1 }, { lat: 40.7168, lng: -73.9861, count: 1 }, { lat: 47.7294, lng: -116.757, count: 1 }, { lat: 47.7294, lng: -116.757, count: 2 }, { lat: 35.5498, lng: -118.917, count: 1 }, { lat: 34.1568, lng: -118.523, count: 1 }, { lat: 39.501, lng: -87.3919, count: 3 }, { lat: 33.5586, lng: -112.095, count: 1 }, { lat: 38.757, lng: -77.1487, count: 1 }, { lat: 33.223, lng: -117.107, count: 1 }, { lat: 30.2316, lng: -85.502, count: 1 }, { lat: 39.1703, lng: -75.5456, count: 8 }, { lat: 30.0041, lng: -95.2984, count: 2 }, { lat: 29.7755, lng: -95.4152, count: 1 }, { lat: 41.8014, lng: -87.6005, count: 1 }, { lat: 37.8754, lng: -121.687, count: 7 }, { lat: 38.4493, lng: -122.709, count: 1 }, { lat: 40.5494, lng: -89.6252, count: 1 }, { lat: 42.6105, lng: -71.2306, count: 1 }, { lat: 40.0973, lng: -85.671, count: 1 }, { lat: 40.3987, lng: -86.8642, count: 1 }, { lat: 40.4224, lng: -86.8031, count: 4 }, { lat: 47.2166, lng: -122.451, count: 1 }, { lat: 32.2369, lng: -110.956, count: 1 }, { lat: 41.3969, lng: -87.3274, count: 2 }, { lat: 41.7364, lng: -89.7043, count: 2 }, { lat: 42.3425, lng: -71.0677, count: 1 }, { lat: 33.8042, lng: -83.8893, count: 1 }, { lat: 36.6859, lng: -121.629, count: 2 }, { lat: 41.0957, lng: -80.5052, count: 1 }, { lat: 46.8841, lng: -123.995, count: 1 }, { lat: 40.2851, lng: -75.9523, count: 2 }, { lat: 42.4235, lng: -85.3992, count: 1 }, { lat: 39.7437, lng: -104.979, count: 2 }, { lat: 25.6586, lng: -80.3568, count: 7 }, { lat: 33.0975, lng: -80.1753, count: 1 }, { lat: 25.7615, lng: -80.2939, count: 1 }, { lat: 26.3739, lng: -80.1468, count: 1 }, { lat: 37.6454, lng: -84.8171, count: 1 }, { lat: 34.2321, lng: -77.8835, count: 1 }, { lat: 34.6774, lng: -82.928, count: 1 }, { lat: 39.9744, lng: -86.0779, count: 1 }, { lat: 35.6784, lng: -97.4944, count: 2 }, { lat: 33.5547, lng: -84.1872, count: 1 }, { lat: 27.2498, lng: -80.3797, count: 1 }, { lat: 41.4789, lng: -81.6473, count: 1 }, { lat: 41.813, lng: -87.7134, count: 1 }, { lat: 41.8917, lng: -87.9359, count: 1 }, { lat: 35.0911, lng: -89.651, count: 1 }, { lat: 32.6102, lng: -117.03, count: 1 }, { lat: 41.758, lng: -72.7444, count: 1 }, { lat: 39.8062, lng: -86.1407, count: 1 }, { lat: 41.872, lng: -88.1662, count: 1 }, { lat: 34.1404, lng: -81.3369, count: 1 }, { lat: 46.15, lng: -60.1667, count: 1 }, { lat: 36.0679, lng: -86.7194, count: 1 }, { lat: 43.45, lng: -80.5, count: 1 }, { lat: 44.3833, lng: -79.7, count: 1 }, { lat: 45.4167, lng: -75.7, count: 2 }, { lat: 43.75, lng: -79.2, count: 2 }, { lat: 45.2667, lng: -66.0667, count: 3 }, { lat: 42.9833, lng: -81.25, count: 2 }, { lat: 44.25, lng: -79.4667, count: 3 }, { lat: 45.2667, lng: -66.0667, count: 2 }, { lat: 34.3667, lng: -118.478, count: 3 }, { lat: 42.734, lng: -87.8211, count: 1 }, { lat: 39.9738, lng: -86.1765, count: 1 }, { lat: 33.7438, lng: -117.866, count: 1 }, { lat: 37.5741, lng: -122.321, count: 1 }, { lat: 42.2843, lng: -85.2293, count: 1 }, { lat: 34.6574, lng: -92.5295, count: 1 }, { lat: 41.4881, lng: -87.4424, count: 1 }, { lat: 25.72, lng: -80.2707, count: 1 }, { lat: 34.5873, lng: -118.245, count: 1 }, { lat: 35.8278, lng: -78.6421, count: 1 }] };
        var baseLayer = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            { attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>', maxZoom: 18 });
        var cfg = {
            "radius": 4,
            "maxOpacity": .6,
            "scaleRadius": true,
            "useLocalExtrema": true,
            latField: 'lat',
            lngField: 'lng',
            valueField: 'count'
        };

        var heatmapLayer = new HeatmapOverlay(cfg);
        var map = new L.Map('map-canvas', {
            center: new L.LatLng(25.6586, -80.3568),
            zoom: 4,
            layers: [baseLayer, heatmapLayer]
        });
        heatmapLayer.setData(testData);
    }
}
```

With the urls in the header, it produces the following heatmap:

[image: Leaflet heatmap]

Now I want to move the references for leaflet, heatmap and leaflet-heatmap to webpack. In my webpack vendor file, I have added the following urls to my modules to import:

```
const modulesToImport = [
......
"leaflet",
"leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
"heatmap.js/build/heatmap.min.js",
"leaflet-heatmap/leaflet-heatmap.js"
];
```

after which I run webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js.

I then run the site, click to the Network tab in Chrome, and take a look in the vendor.js file and it now contains the contents of leafletjs, heatmap.min.js and leaflet-heatmap.js. The vendor css file contains the leaflet.css.

But when I run the app, the component crashes on the HeatmapOverlay statement. It says: "ERROR ReferenceError: HeatmapOverlay is not defined"

How can I get the application to recognise and use the HeatmapOverlay object found in the leaflet-heatmap.js file?

Note that if I comment out the Heatmap related lines of code, the map does display, so the leaflet part itself is working.

Comment: I have put the code in a repo: https://github.com/tonywr71/Heatmap

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding this to my webpack.config.vendor.js file, in the nonTreeShakableModules section:

```
"leaflet",
"leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
"heatmap.js/build/heatmap.min.js",
"leaflet-heatmap/leaflet-heatmap.js",
```

In my code, I added:

```
import "heatmap.js";
import "leaflet-heatmap";
declare var HeatmapOverlay: any;
```

and it worked after that.